# Forking a Heroku app causes issues with omniauth redirect_uri

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, facebook, heroku, omniauth

I have an staging application on Heroku that is a fork of our existing staging app (most of the same addons and the DB are being used that the existing staging app was) and for some reason I am having issues with omniauth.

When a user tries to sign up using Facebook or Google Plus I am getting the error of `redirect_uri` doesn't match, but I have created separate apps for our new staging environment and for some reason the old `*.herokuapp.com` domain is being passed to the `redirect_uri`... any reason why this would be happening?